# Measuring battery voltage fluctuations and spikes in an analog wall mounted clock when the second hand ticks

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier

As the title suggests, my goal is to be able to pickup minute voltage fluctuations of an AA battery cell of the wall-mounted clock, each time the second hand ticks.

My first intuition would be to ac-couple the battery into an op-amp, perhaps a low-noise instrumentational amplifier, and feed the output into a microcontroller.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to do this for? What is purpose of deriving this signal? Easier way to pick this signal is using magnetic pickup coil placed on top of the motor solenoid of the clock motor. You don't even need to dismantle the clock.

Comment: Depending on what you really want to do, you might be better measuring the current pulses from the battery (by measuring the voltage across a low ( 1 ohm) resistor in series with the battery. This will stay approximately the same (30mA, 30ms) throughout the battery life, while the voltage fluctuations will vary as the battery depletes (its internal resistance increases). The latter, of course, tells you when it's becoming time to replace the battery.

Comment: Similar to the above two suggestions, you could thread the connection via a wire from the AA cell to the clock through a small toroidal magnetic core and wind a dozen or so secondary turns onto the core. Load the secondary with something like 10K and look at the trace on an oscilloscope and adjust the transformer and amplify the signal.. You don't disclose your location, but suitable cores are maybe 50 cents from Digikey.

Comment: @soosaisteven That is a great idea. My intention is to some how get the time the clock is showing, and calculate how far off it has  drifted from the real time. ±30 seconds over an hour period is acceptable (around 9%). My idea is to count the number of passing seconds and send the signal to a PC which is synchronized with a NTP server, and whenever the difference of real time and the clock time has reached ±30 seconds just light up an LED.
As a requirement, the installation should be super simple without taking the clock apart, and your solution satisfies it very elegantly.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for the great idea. About taking the current measurement instead of voltage you are absolutely right, but I wonder why ac-coupling doesn't get rid of any dc offset? We are just interested in voltage transients no matter of the state of the cell, aren't we? Am I missing a point?

Comment: Of course AC coupling gets rid of DC offsets.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You are absolutely right. As soosaisteven also mentioned, it is much easier approach compared to instrumentational amplifiers.
This is my very first attempt to design an electronic circuit! I would be very happy and grateful if you could please just elaborate a bit more about the differences of each method (instrumentational amplifiers vs magnetic pickup coil) and their appropriate application.

Thanks